# jsonwebtoken not in headers

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have a problem with jsonwebtoken in a express app, I can't verify a jwt on a middleware because jwt is not present in req.headers here's my code :

```
const payload = { email, role: "User" };

jwt.sign(
        payload,
        process.env.SECRET_USER,
        {
           expiresIn: 60
        },
        (err, token) => {
        if (err) return err;
           res.send(token);
        }
    );
```

When I use postman, I don't have an error and the token is successfully send.
But in my middleware (for check if a user is logged), I try console.log(req.headers) and there's no keys "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]"

The Middleware :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

exports.isUserAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.headers);
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
};
```

Comment: Please give us the code of the middleware where you wanna get the Auth-Header as well.

Comment: How is your client calling the API and attaching the token?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the token before making your request to the server from the client ?
For example assuming you are using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make http request after the user is logged in :

```
axios.get('/check', {
     headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'bear-token-received-after-user-logged-in'
    }})
```

You need to supply the token each time you make a request to the server.